# Proving an astroid is a simply connected subspace of the plane

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis

How do I prove the following to be a **simply connected** space?

$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid (x-5)^{2/3}+(y-7)^{2/3}<1\}$$

An  astroid which centered at $(5,7)$.

Comment: Show that it is star-shaped.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}<1\}$ is a star shaped subset of the plane. Star shaped subsets of the plane are simply connected via a usual straight line homotopy argument. It is clear that the space in the question is homeomorphic via a translation to $A$ and so must also be simply connected as homeomorphisms preserve simple connectivity.

To prove that $A$ is star shaped, let $(x_0,y_0)$ be an elements in $A$ and let $w_t=t\cdot(x_0,y_0)$. In order to prove that $A$ is star shaped, we have to show that $w_t\in A$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. The point $w_t$ has coordinates $tx_0$ and $ty_0$, and we see that $(tx_0)^{2/3}+(ty_0)^{2/3}=t^{2/3}(x_0^{2/3}+y_0^{2/3})< t^{2/3}$ because $(x_0,y_0)\in A$. As $0\leq t\leq 1$, it follows that $t^{2/3}\leq 1$ and so $w_t\in A$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @rozeshmonim Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if you feel it answered your question well.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\phi((s_1,s_2)) = (s_1^3+5,s_2^3+7)$. Note that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Let $S = \{ (x,y) | (x-5)^{\frac{2}{3}} + (y-7)^{\frac{2}{3}} < 1 \}$, and note that $\phi(B(0,1)) = S$. The set $B(0,1)$ is convex, hence simply connected.

Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ be two paths in $S$, and define $h:[0,1]\times[0,1] \to S$ by $h(t,\lambda) = \phi((1-\lambda)\phi^{-1}(\gamma_1(t))+\lambda \phi^{-1}(\gamma_2(t)))$. Then $h$ is a homotopy between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. Hence $S$ is simply connected.

Comment: What's $B(0,1)$?

Comment: $\{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2 < 1\}$.